# find duplicates in a string in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample df

```
id        name
 1        John Walter walter
 2        Adam Smith Smith
 3        Steve Rogers rogers
```

How can I find whether it is duplicated in every row and pop it out?

```
id        name                    is_duplicated    poped_out_string     corrected_name
 1        John Walter walter             1               walter             John walter
 2        Adam Smith Smith               1               walter             Adam Smith
 3        Steve Rogers rogers            1               walter             Steve Rogers
```

Comment: Why is the popped out string "walter" for every row?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['dup'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().to_string(index=False), axis=1)
```

Assuming that you have set the string in the data frame as `df`, this code will find whether the value is duplicated in every row and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `more_itertools.unique_everseen`

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

def unique(arr, key):
    return " ".join(unique_everseen(arr, key=key))

df["name"].str.split().apply(unique, key=str.lower)
```

Output:

```
0     John Walter
1      Adam Smith
2    Steve Rogers
Name: name, dtype: object
```

If you don't want `more_itertools`, you can still use `unique_everseen` from `itertools` recipes:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `set` to de-duplicate and a `collections.Counter` to get the duplicated values -

```py
df['corrected_name'] = df['name'].str.split().apply(lambda x: ' '.join(set(map(str.lower, x)))).str.title()
df['popped_out_string'] = df['name'].str.split().apply(lambda x: ''.join(k for k, v in Counter(map(str.lower, x)).items() if v > 1))
```

**Output**

```
   id                 name corrected_name popped_out_string
0   1   John Walter walter    John Walter            walter
1   2     Adam Smith Smith     Smith Adam             smith
2   3  Steve Rogers rogers   Rogers Steve            rogers
```

Comment: Why the name `Adam Smith Smith` has changed to `Smith Adam` instead of `Adam Smith`?

Comment: Good catch! Probably `set` re-ordering items.